# sklearn MeanShift different prediction output

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Why do I get different outputs from line

```
print ms.fit_predict(val), p_all[idx]
```

The outputs from ms.fit_predict(val) are all 0.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import MeanShift, estimate_bandwidth

X = 100*np.random.random_sample((500,15))-100
X = np.array(X, dtype=np.float)
bandwidth = estimate_bandwidth(X, quantile=0.01)
ms = MeanShift(bandwidth=bandwidth, bin_seeding=True)
ms.fit(X)
p_all = ms.fit_predict(X)
for idx, val in enumerate(X):
    print val
    print X[idx]
    print ms.fit_predict(val), p_all[idx]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're re-fitting inside a loop, to a single data point. `p_all` is the cluster assignments of fitting to all of the data in `X`. After the loop runs, if you print out `ms.cluster_centers_`, it will be the same as `val`, because it is fit **only** to `val`. Thus, there will be only a single cluster, and its index is `0`.

I'm guessing you're confused about the interface to `MeanShift`. It doesn't refit online. Every time you call `fit()` or `fit_predict()`, it fits only to the data you pass it, and ignores the old solution.

I'd suggest having a look at the [sklearn MeanShift documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.MeanShift.html)

Comment: Thanks, I really need to use http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.MeanShift.html#sklearn.cluster.MeanShift.predict in order to get the same output.